# Zoomable inline SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have an inline `SVG` inside a `div` and simply I want to make it **zoomable** and able to **pan** using `drag`. I've search everywhere and found nothing that suits my needs. I dont want `.svg` files or whatever. Just an inline `SVG` inside a `div`.

I found this thing but it freeze my brain. I don't get it. But the demo in this [**link**](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999) suits my needs. But I don't get it. Please if anyone have an idea how to achieve that one thanks a lot in advance. I tried my best that I come up with asking here guys. I'm new to `SVG` so please be patient with me. :)

Comment: You can do it using d3 ,the link that you have provided is using d3 only.

Comment: @Roshanjha, but how can I do it? All I see in the link that I provided is `script` tags. No `inline SVG` or a `SVG` file either. BTW my inline `svg` is a map that manipulated using `ID` and `class` so that as long as possible I want an inline SVG. Please if you have any tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the things that you are doing in your HTML file can be done using d3 .For reference read [this](http://d3js.org/)

In my example i have simply taken one circle and zooming it

```
var svg = d3.select("#mydiv").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 1000)
      .append("g")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
      .append("g");

var circle = svg.append("circle")
                         .attr("cx", 70)
                         .attr("cy", 200)
                         .attr("r", 20);

function zoom() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

HTML is

```
<div id="mydiv">
</div>
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhaRoshan/2fy8safb/)

Now what actually we are doing is that we are appending svg in a div using d3 and applying zoom behaviour there.

Comment: If you have any problem feel free to ask

Comment: Wooooowwwww!!!! That's amazing.... But my map contains `path` not `rect` or even `circle`. How can I append that and set the `attr`. Can you provide me example using `path`? Thanks sir :)

Comment: Can't get to it :( I can draw a path but can't zoom in, plus it's so hard to manually put the x and y coordinates. Is there some tools for converting it? Here's my http://jsfiddle.net/2fy8safb/1/

Comment: Fixed it :) Now for drawing my path. It's hard to write it manually, really :( http://jsfiddle.net/2fy8safb/2/